# need help on searching multiple elements using lxml XPATH

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have the following XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Bdpo>
  <ListaRegistrosBdpo>
    <RegistroBdpo>
      <Empresa>03271</Empresa>
      <DataRegistro>2018-03-27</DataRegistro>
      <DataOcorrencia>2017-11-08</DataOcorrencia>
      <DataReconhecimento>2017-11-17</DataReconhecimento>
      <NumeroEvento>00008</NumeroEvento>
      <TipoEvento>6</TipoEvento>
      <PerdaRaizDataRegistro>2018-02-08</PerdaRaizDataRegistro>
      <PerdaRaizNumeroEvento>00250</PerdaRaizNumeroEvento>
      <Categoria>7</Categoria>
      <OrigemJudicial>1</OrigemJudicial>
      <ContabilizadaPsl>2</ContabilizadaPsl>
      <FuncaoNegocio>1</FuncaoNegocio>
      <CausaPerda>2</CausaPerda>
      <StatusPerda>2</StatusPerda>
      <ValorBruto>0.00</ValorBruto>
      <DescricaoEvento>123</DescricaoEvento>
      <IdInternaEvento>Pasta 95</IdInternaEvento>
    </RegistroBdpo>
    <RegistroBdpo>
      <Empresa>03271</Empresa>
      <DataRegistro>2018-03-27</DataRegistro>
      <DataOcorrencia>2017-11-08</DataOcorrencia>
      <DataReconhecimento>2017-11-17</DataReconhecimento>
      <NumeroEvento>00007</NumeroEvento>
      <TipoEvento>6</TipoEvento>
      <PerdaRaizDataRegistro>2018-02-08</PerdaRaizDataRegistro>
      <PerdaRaizNumeroEvento>00248</PerdaRaizNumeroEvento>
      <Categoria>7</Categoria>
      <OrigemJudicial>1</OrigemJudicial>
      <ContabilizadaPsl>2</ContabilizadaPsl>
      <FuncaoNegocio>1</FuncaoNegocio>
      <CausaPerda>2</CausaPerda>
      <StatusPerda>2</StatusPerda>
      <ValorBruto>0.00</ValorBruto>
      <DescricaoEvento>123</DescricaoEvento>
      <IdInternaEvento>Pasta 41</IdInternaEvento>
    </RegistroBdpo>
    (...)
  </ListaRegistrosBdpo>
</Bdpo>
```

I want to search RegistroBdpo elements that match the following criteria:

1. *TipoEvento* tag is equal to 5 OR 6
2. *PerdaRaizNumeroEvento* tag is equal to 00250
   and return their Id tag (IdInternaEvento).

I have tried the following code:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
  
r = ET.parse(xml_file_location)

string = './/*RegistroBdpo[TipoEvento="5" or TipoEvento="6"][PerdaRaizNumeroEvento="00250"]'
[ reg.find('IdInternaEvento').text for reg in r.iterfind(string) ]
```

But I get the error: *SyntaxError: invalid predicate*

Any ideas on what I did wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of XPath you simply want `//RegistroBdpo[TipoEvento=5 or TipoEvento=6][PerdaRaizNumeroEvento="00534"]/IdInternaEvento`. Or rather `//RegistroBdpo[TipoEvento=5 or TipoEvento=6][PerdaRaizNumeroEvento="00250"]/IdInternaEvento`, depending on the value given in the text versus your code sample.

In Python with lxml you can use e.g. `ids = r.xpath('//RegistroBdpo[TipoEvento=5 or TipoEvento=6][PerdaRaizNumeroEvento="00250"]/IdInternaEvento')`

Comment: I got the error "lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Error in xpath expression"

Comment: I tried the code with Python 3.7 and lxml 4.6.3 on Windows and the code works fine and returns the element with `Pasta 95` from your sample input. Not sure where your attempt fails, perhaps edit the question to show the sample you have.